# sonar-maven-plugin not parse sonar.branch variable

Tags: maven, sonarqube

My pom.xml contains:

```
    ...
<properties>
    <sonar.branch>${git.branch}</sonar.branch>
</properties>
    ...
```

${git.branch} is resolved as "master", but sonar failed build with:

> ""${git.branch}" is not a valid branch name. Allowed characters are
>   alphanumeric, '-', '_', '.' and '/'."

```
SonarQube server 5.1.2
sonar-maven-plugin 2.7.1
```

Edit:

My pom.xml:

```
    ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.concerteza.buildnumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jgit-buildnumber-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-buildnumber</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>extract-buildnumber</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    ...
    <profile>
        <id>sonar-analyze</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sonar-analyze</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sonar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
                                <sonar.branch>${git.branch}</sonar.branch>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    ...
```

command for run:

```
mvn clean install -Dsonar-analyze
```

With this approach I had another problem, sonar launched analyzing for all modules in multimodule project many times.
Finally removed this code from pom.xml
and pass sonar branch as parameter:

```
clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${GIT_BRANCH}
```

Comment: I guess you are using a plugin to populate the property ${git.branch}. To which phase is the plugin attached? What is the command you are using to run the SQ analysis? Try single line: `mvn verify sonar:sonar`